# Copy large files to multiple machines on a LAN

Tags: linux, file-sharing

I have a few large files that I need to copy from one Linux machine to about 20 other Linux machines, all on the same LAN as quickly as is feasible.  What tools/methods would be best for copying these files, noting that this is not going to be a one-time copy.  These machines will never be connected to the Internet, and security is not an issue.

**Update:**

The reason for my asking this is because (as I understand it) we are currently using `scp` in serial to copy the files to each of the machines and I have been informed that this is "too slow" and a faster alternative is being sought.  According to what I have been told, attempting to parallelize the `scp` calls simply slows it down further due to hard drive seeks.

Comment: Define "large". Hundreds of MB/GB/TB/more?

Comment: Currently, the total is sitting at about 4 GiB (compressed), although that may grow in the future.

Comment: That is, by any means even in 2011 - NOT LARGE. Given a 1gigabit link that is properly switched (standard in 2011) that is quite fas to accomplish. Running it of a 10g server (not that rare even in 2011)... well ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

BitTorrent. It's how Twitter deploys some things internally.

[http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/07/murder-fast-datacenter-code-deploys.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20111202023000/http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/07/murder-fast-datacenter-code-deploys.html) (web archive link)

Comment: Now that is clever :)

Comment: I'll try this and see how well it works in our environment

Comment: In addition to my answer (which I do think will do a good job, if you can implement it), the below answer for NFS is a very good one. A good NFS server should cache files so you won't keep hitting disk. Also, with that, don't copy the files *from* the server *to* the clients. Initiate it from the client and let the NFS server's cache help out.

Comment: Be sure to try it in a non-production environnement, in the presentation they say (iirc) it made some switches suffer a lot during the first deployments because of the number of packets exchanged.

Comment: I would love to favourite this answer

Comment: That's not going to be any faster since it still has to send all of the data 20 times.  You want a multicast solution so the data is only sent once.

Comment: @psusi Why do you say it has to send all of the data 20 times? Once the other peers have part of the file, they can start sending the parts they have to the other peers themselves.

Comment: @JonathanCallen, whether it is the original server or one of the peers doesn't matter; the data still has to be sent over the lan once for every client.  In fact, bit torrent sometimes sends the same chunk twice by accident.  I suppose though, that if your switch has a multi gigabit backplane then multiple machines sending to each other could end up going faster than the single server sending 20 times, but still the best solution is to multicast the data just once.

Comment: The problem for the OP is not the LAN, it's the disk on the central server.

Comment: @pSusi - multicast would certainly be another valid answer. Post that as an answer, not as a knock on my answer.

Comment: @mfinni, what makes you think that?  Any decent server hd should have no problem keeping up with a gigabit lan.  A good single disk can handle 100 MB/s these days, let alone any kind of raid.

Comment: From the OP : "According to what I have been told, attempting to parallelize the scp calls simply slows it down further due to hard drive seeks." That's what makes me think that.

Comment: Facebook deploy with BitTorrent too - http://torrentfreak.com/facebook-uses-bittorrent-and-they-love-it-100625/

Answer (score 12):

How about [UFTP](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net), it uses multicast to deliver files over UDP to multiple clients at once. Not for everyone and I'm no expert on it but it sounds like it does what you want.

Comment: Disclaimer: This will require equipment that supports multicast.

Comment: I was rather hoping this'd be on the same vlan - reducing the impact of this use.

Comment: @user606723: Doesn't everything modern? Maybe some consumer junk does not, but I haven't run into anything with broken multicast in a while. Too much uses it these days. I think Windows Active Directory even uses multicast.

Comment: I actually have no experience with this @ZanLynx. I know that many offices/computer labs use consumer/unmanaged switches at the last hop. How will these switches behave with multicast?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to copy this data with `rsync`? If you have 1 Gbit LAN or faster, copying over 4*20 GB should not be a problem.

How often will this copy occur? Does it matter if it takes couple of minutes to finish?

Answer (score 3):

scp-tsunami it's the way!

https://code.google.com/p/scp-tsunami/

It's commonly used to distribute disk images on virtualization clusters, its performances are near bittorrent but it's simpler to use for daily usage.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up an NFS share and having each machine pull from this shared repo of large files would likely be the fastest method (NFS is very quick and has little overhead).

You could add an additional NIC or two to the source server and bond them together to give you better throughput.

Implementation could be a simple cron job on each target server that blindly fetches from the share every hour/day/whatever.  You could also setup a daemon to poll for new files; you could also just script a control session to SSH (with key pairs) into each target box and instruct them to fetch the file when you execute your script.

Comment: I believe my predecessor attempted to use NFS for this and found that (at the time), the RAM cache wasn't large enough for the entire transfer, which was causing the load on the hard drive to become the limiting factor instead of the network speed.